# Database with timestamps, show distinct month

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, distinct, between

I have a table that saves my upload / download statistics per 15 minutes.

This is what the table looks like

```
| ID  | timestamp  | upload | download | packetssent | packetsreceived 
| 1   | 1328828401 | 343245 | 93473463 | 4343423     | 3435664
| 2   | 1328829301 | 343245 | 93473463 | 4343423     | 3435664
```

What i want is when you come first on the page you see total download/upload. And then a list of the months available. (So currently is that only February), Once you click on a month, it wil show the day's and their totals, when you click on a day, you will see all records for that single day

I need advice how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SELECT  month(timestamp), sum(packetssent) from table group by month(timestamp) you looking for this?

You have also day and year

Comment: SELECT month(timestamp), sum(packetssent) from table group by month(timestamp) >> Returns null

What i want is when you come first on the page you see total download/upload. And then a list of the months available. (So currently is that only February), Once you click on a month, it wil show the day's and their totals, when you click on a day, you will see all records for that single day.

Comment: Depending on your usage you may want to look at denormalising this data and building up daily/monthly aggregate tables to avoid performing the same queries on what is effectively static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (for the current year):

```
SELECT 
   FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%m") AS m, 
   FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp, "%Y") AS Y, 
   SUM(packetssent ) AS sent, 
   SUM(packetsreceived) AS received
FROM atable
GROUP BY Y, m HAVING Y=YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the various values, use the date/time functions in MySQL

```
DAY(from_unixtime(timestamp))
MONTH(from_unixtime(timestamp))
YEAR(from_unixtime(timestamp))

HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
SECOND(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))
```

You can use these in `group by` sections to extract your information dependent on a variety of time frames

Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html for a full list

Comment: +1 although FROM_UNIXTIME(t, "%d"), FROM_UNIXTIME(t, "%m"), FROM_UNIXTIME(t, "%Y"), etc can avoid the extra function call in the syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(DATE(timestamp)) FROM Table.
```

You might get away with

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(timestamp) FROM table.
```

but if you can the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) for the MONTH() function doesn't state that you can pass a timestamp to it.

Comment: Will that not select all the rows for the same month in different years?  Maybe that's what the OP wants, but if he wants to limit it to specific years will he also need to get the year out of the timestamp as well?

Comment: Aye; if the OP wants to further split by year then they'll need extend the above accordingly but they've not asked that so I'll leave it out for now.

Comment: Fair enough.  Just thought I'd get that out there ;)